# How to jump and animate body like mario game character?

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to 'andengine' and I developing simple game like 'mario' so I want to jump and move that character in a proper way.

Please give me some ideas, I use velocity and impulse but that is not working properly.

Comment: Can you post what you have atm?

Comment: i don't know what is meaning of atm?

Comment: "I am new" and "I want" are not proper way of asking questions here, posting code helps a lot.

Comment: "not working properly" ? to broad...

Comment: [atm](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=atm%20%28at%20the%20moment%29) stands for "At the moment"

Comment: If you are new and developing mario like game then you have to look towards this tutorial series you definitely got something. http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndEngineExamples project contains several sample games which are similar to your application. 
You can download APK and tryout first before digging into the code.

[AndEngineExamples](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it (my interface to my Player class):

```
public void moveLeft() {
    Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(-speed, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);                   
    Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);

    int offset = isInjured ? 4 : 0;     
    if (!isAnimationRunning()) {
        setCurrentTileIndex(2 + offset);
        animate(new long[]{200, 200}, 2 + offset, 3 + offset, 1, animationListener);    
    }
}

public void moveRight() {
    Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(speed, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);               
    Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);  

    int offset = isInjured ? 4 : 0; 
    if (!isAnimationRunning()) {
        setCurrentTileIndex(0 + offset);
        animate(new long[]{200, 200}, 0 + offset, 1 + offset, 1, animationListener);        
    }
}

public void stop() {
    Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(0, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);                   
    Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);

    stopAnimation();

    int offset = isInjured ? 4 : 0;
    if(getCurrentTileIndex() % 4 > 1 ) 
        setCurrentTileIndex(2 + offset);
    else 
        setCurrentTileIndex(0 + offset);
}

public void stopJump() {
    if(jumpsLeft > 0) {
        Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(body.getLinearVelocity().x, body.getLinearVelocity().y / 5);
        body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);                   
        Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);  
    }
}

public void jump() {
    if(jumpsLeft > 0) {
        Vector2 impulse = Vector2Pool.obtain(0, body.getMass() * -12);
        body.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, body.getWorldCenter());                
        Vector2Pool.recycle(impulse);   
        jumpsLeft--;
    }
}
```

Then, I created buttons for moving left, right, jumping, etc.
In the AreaTouched event, for action down, I do `player.jump()`.
For action up, I do `player.stopJump()`.
The code for the move_left and move_right buttons is pretty much the same.